# How can I make ma webbrowser working independent from the System.Thread.Sleep?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sleep

I want to load a page and then stop other action for sleep(time), but the page load after Sleep. How can I prevent that and after loading succesfully a page go to sleep command?

```
myWebBrowser.Url = new Uri("myadress");
System.Thread.Sleep(10000);
// other instructions...
```

Comment: The question is why you want to put the "Page to sleep" at first point.

Comment: Because the page works in background (is invisible in the form) and I use this webbrowser for youtube music. When I use thread it starts after sleep() and I have to wait x seconds for music

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you write thread.sleep(1000); in Completed  event for webbroswer!